# How can we define "curve" in elementary geometry (without using the notion of function)?

Tags: geometry, continuity, euclidean-geometry, curves

Most of definitions of a curve are based on the notion of continuous function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve).

But continuous function is not an instrument to produce a continuous curve in general. The simple example $f(q) = q$ for all $q \in \mathbb Q$ shows us that a continuous function applied to a non-continuous domain may have a non-continuous graph.

Thus, we take an object that does not generate a continuous curve in general and apply it to another object, the real numbers. And how do we know the result is a continuous curve? Because we defined it this way.

This looks like a broken logic. I would expect the following logical steps:

1. We must have a definition of a continuous curve at least for some class of curves, at least in Euclidean 2D and 3D spaces;
2. Then we provide a definition of a continuous transformation and check if the result of such transformation is in agreement with the first definition;
3. Once we satisfied with the comparison, we can drop the first definition and take the second one as a generalization.

However, encyclopedia says: “In elementary geometry the concept of a curve is not clearly defined” (https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Line_(curve)).

I cannot believe mathematicians stopped trying to give a definition of a curve for elementary geometry (may I call it a Euclidean curve?):

- The definition should not use the notion of function or map;
- It should cover all primitive curves like intervals, arcs, etc.;
- It should not be a composition of primitive or predefined curves;
- It should be easily compared with the definition of a continuous function for verification.

Maybe, somebody knows examples of such definitions?
I am looking for a definition that can be shown in a high school, at least as an example.

Comment: **1** Stephen Willard, *General Topology* (Dover 2004), Theorem 28.13: If $K$ is a metric continuum with exactly two noncut points, then $K$ is homeomorphic to the unit interval $I$. **2** Gordon T. Whyburn, *Topological Analysis* (2nd ed. 1964), Theorem 4.2: In order that a continuum $T$ be a simple arc from $a$ to $b$ where $a, b \in T$ it is necessary and sufficient that every point of $T-a-b$ separate $a$ and $b$ in $T$. **3** [Topological characterization of the closed interval $[0,1]$ - MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/123760). Are these the sort of theorems you are looking for?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99733/discussion-on-question-by-alex-c-how-can-we-define-curve-in-elementary-geometr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt (for a curve that may cross itself):
a Euclidean curve is a set of points in a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ with the following properties:

1. It has a linear order $<$;
2. It is dense:

   - for any two points $A < A'$ of the curve, and any length $l > 0$ there are points $B < B'$ of the curve such that $A < B < B' < A'$ and $|BB'| < l$;
3. It is complete:

   - for every sequence of segments $|AA'| > |BB' > |CC'| > ... $, $A < B < C < ... < C' < B' < A'$, where the length of the segments converges to $0$, there is a limit point belonging to the curve;
4. We can measure length between any two points:

   - for any two points of the curve $A < A'$ there is an upper limit of sums of the lengths of consecutive segments $|AB| + |BC| + ... + |C'B'| + |B'A'|$, where $A < B < C < ... < C' < B' < A'$.

Definition: a limit point $X$ for a sequence of segments $|AA'| > |BB' > |CC'| > ... $, $A < B < C < ... < C' < B' < A'$ is a *crossing* point if $X < A$ or $X > A'$.

5. All *crossing* points of a curve are isolated:

   - for any *crossing* point $X$ there is a distance $d > 0$ such that for any *crossing* point $Y \ne X$: $|XY| > d$.

Comment: Have you seen Cantor's characterisation of the order type of closed intervals? The order topology on a set $I$ satisfying Cantor's criteria (or similar ones in books such as Potter, *Sets* or Moschovakis, *Notes on Set Theory*) is compact, so an injection into a Hausdorff space, $f\colon I\to X$, is a homeomorphism. It thus seems possible to characterise the image $f(I)$ of such a map as an ordered subset of $X$, satisfying C-like criteria, with order topology finer than subspace topology. I've been meaning to check this, but haven't had time. (I'll delete it if wrong - don't want to mislead!)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: I will check it. Thank you!